# Move up label animation inside CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I have horizontally scrolling `CollectionView` with unknown amount of cells, which takes the entire screen except nav bar. And `CollectionViewCell`, which takes the entire `CollectionView`. Also, inside this cell I have centered `UIView` with some Labels and one button inside. This is how my UI looks like: [click](http://i-fotki.info/22/2f3c9b565f91fb6f50735d4c5f1b8b25059fe5284937703.png.html).

Whenever user clicks on the button inside this UIView, label moves up a little bit, and also all other labels become visible. If this mode has already been activated, button works in the opposite way:

```
class WordCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var isActive = false
@IBOutlet weak var word: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var translation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var exOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var exTwo: UILabel!

// ...

@IBAction func move(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if !isActive {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.word.frame.origin.y -= self.bounds.height / 7
        }, completion: nil)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.translation.alpha = 1
                self.exOne.alpha = 1
                self.exTwo.alpha = 1
            })
            isActive = true
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.word.frame.origin.y += self.bounds.height / 7
            }, completion: nil)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.translation.alpha = 0
                self.exOne.alpha = 0
                self.exTwo.alpha = 0
            })
        isActive = false
        }
    }
}
```

And after that my UI looks like: [click](http://i-fotki.info/22/166600ae48c2a1935f8806cb70552565059fe5284937703.png.html)

My CollectionView Code:

```
    // CollectiomView Delegate stuff, in the code above I just retrieve data from FireBase
extension RepeatController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return words.count
        }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "wordCell", for: indexPath) as! WordCell
        if words[0].lPairs == "re" {
            cell.word.text = words[indexPath.row].translation
            cell.translation.text = words[indexPath.row].word

        } else {
            cell.word.text = words[indexPath.row].word
            cell.translation.text = words[indexPath.row].translation
        }
        cell.exOne.text = words[indexPath.row].exOne
        cell.exTwo.text = words[indexPath.row].exTwo
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let bounds = collectionView.bounds
        return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    }

}
```

**Problem:**

This system works only if I click button twice (move up label and then return it to the same position and hide all other labels). Otherwise, after 2-3 Cells all other labels become visible and main Label is on the top, like I've typed on the button for each cell (but I haven't). What is the problem?

Comment: Just a wild guess: this could be an effect of cell reuse. Normally TableView/CollectionView cells are [recycled/reused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600645/uicollectionview-without-reusing-cells), the datasource should be separate - they are representation only. See: [dequeueReusableCell Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618063-dequeuereusablecell) and also the [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse) method which should reset your `WordCell`.

Comment: @Oleg Blanutsa Whenever you update UI , you should do it in DispatchQueue.main.async block, please make this change in your code and tell the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the change is in UI , so first I think you should first put your animation code inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` block

Then since you are using reusable collection view cells, values that you change in animation code remain same for the cell that is reused, so to give these values some initial value before the collection view reuses them, we override the `prepareForReuse()` method and give the initial values in there.

Using the idea from documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse)

> When a view is dequeued for use, this method is called before the
>   corresponding dequeue method returns the view to your code. Subclasses
>   can override this method and use it to reset properties to their
>   default values and generally make the view ready to use again

In code you can do this :

```
 @IBAction func move(_ sender: UIButton) {
            if !isActive {
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                          self.word.frame.origin.y -= self.bounds.height / 7
                          }, completion: nil)
                               UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                               self.translation.alpha = 1
                               self.exOne.alpha = 1
                               self.exTwo.alpha = 1
                          })

                  }
                          isActive = true
            } else {
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                         self.word.frame.origin.y += self.bounds.height / 7
                         }, completion: nil)
                         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                               self.translation.alpha = 0
                               self.exOne.alpha = 0
                               self.exTwo.alpha = 0
                         })

                }
                isActive = false
            }
        }
    }

override func prepareForReuse() {

     super.prepareForReuse()

     self.word.frame.origin.y = self.wordTop.constant, //where wordTop is a top constraint for the word 
     isActive = false
     self.translation.alpha = 0
     self.exOne.alpha = 0
     self.exTwo.alpha = 0



}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for collectionview in your post?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @OlegBlanutsa I have made some changes, please check this code and ask question if you face problem

Comment: Well, it solves my previous problem, but also creates a new one. Sometimes movable label is displaced: [click](http://i-fotki.info/22/cde2888f03bf79b85896eb3aa124c230059fe5284943067.png.html) and [click](http://i-fotki.info/22/ee1df2d34fb1b4d78d6402b2dbc05534059fe5284943067.png.html).

Comment: What is the name of this label?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151499/discussion-between-user1000-and-oleg-blanutsa).